# Set UITextField placeholder text colour based on if statements

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uitextfield

In an app I am developing, there is an email address and password UITextField.

I am trying to set conditions so that if either or both are empty ("") when a `SignIn` button is pressed, then the placeholder text should be red, highlighting to the user to complete them.

I am very new to iOS development (Or development in general) so my logical thinking is probably wrong.
Anyway, here is what I wrote and started with:

```
       @IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if emailField.text == "" {
          emailField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email address", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

        if pwdField.text == "" {
            pwdField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])
        }
    }else {
```

This works perfectly if: 
 - Both fields are empty 
 - Email address is empty and password field is filled 
 
 But... if the email address field is filled and the password field is empty, the password field placeholder text does not change.

I would love to know where I'm going wrong or if there's a more simpler/logical way to achieve the result.

Comment: Your if statements are stacked. They should be seperate.

Comment: FYI - use `if emailField.isEmpty {` instead of `if emailField.text == "" {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like swift's way with `{}` so for the example I am showing them different.

**Your code with different indents:**

```
@IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) 
{   
    if emailField.text == "" 
    {
        emailField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email 
            address", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: 
            UIColor.red])

        if pwdField.text == "" 
        {
            pwdField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: 
                "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: 
                UIColor.red])
        }
    }
    else {
```

Notice how your `if` statements are nested.  The `pwdField` will not be checked unless the `emailField` is empty.

To fix it unstack them and note that I moved the `else` and turned it to a `else if`,

**Fixed Code:**

```
@IBAction func signInTapped(_ sender: Any) 
{
    if emailField.text == "" 
    {
        emailField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email 
            address", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: 
            UIColor.red])
    }

    if pwdField == "" 
    {
        pwdField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: 
            "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: 
            UIColor.red])
    }

    else if emailField.text != "" 
    { 
         //here both fields have text inside them
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You have an If statement inside another if statement.

Instead of this:

```
if emailField.text == "" {
          emailField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email address", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

        if pwdField.text == "" {
            pwdField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])
        }
}
```

Use this:

```
if emailField.text == "" {
          emailField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email address", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])
}

if pwdField.text == "" {
            pwdField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])
}
```

Hope this helps!